# WPF-Deleting DataGrid row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

I want to delete a row from a WPF DataGrid that I fill with a query with data from two tables.
With the traditional way using a single unique table, delete works, but with query, it doesn't get the value of the cell that contains the code throws a null reference error.

The DataGrid xaml code

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding idInscrito}" Width="120"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IdAlumno" Binding="{Binding IdAlum}" Width="120"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Matricula" Binding="{Binding matricula}" Width="150"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Apellido" Binding="{Binding apellido}" Width="250"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding nombre}" Width="150"/>
                    <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Accion" Width="150"/>-->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Accion"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Button x:Name="btnBorrar" Cursor="Hand" Style="{StaticResource Boton}" Content="Borrar" Click="btnBorrar_Click">
                                        <Button.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Resources>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Code behind: Filling the DataGrid

```
var alumn = (from v in _db.inscritos
                             join b in _db.alumnos on v.IdAlum equals b.IdAlum
                             where v.idNivel == (int?)comboNivel.SelectedValue && v.idSec == (int?)comboSeccion.SelectedValue
                             orderby b.apellido
                             select new {v.idInscrito, v.IdAlum, v.matricula, b.apellido, b.nombre }).ToList();
```

Delete Button Click event

```
int id = (int)(GridInscritos.SelectedItem as Curso).idInscrito;//Here doesnt get de code value
                var ins = _db.inscritos.Where(a => a.IdAlum == id).SingleOrDefault();
                _db.inscritos.Remove(ins);
                _db.SaveChanges();
```

I want to delete the DataGrid row selected and in the base table too.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedItem` property returns an anonymous object since you set the `ItemsSource` to a list of such objects.

You can use the `dynamic` keyword to get the value of the `idInscrito` property:

```
dynamic selectedItem = GridInscritos.SelectedItem;
int id = selectedItem.idInscrito;
var ins = ...;
```

If you want compile-time safety, you should create a type with the `idInscrito`, `IdAlum`, `matricula`, `apellido` and `nombre` properties instead of populating the `DataGrid` with anonymous objects.

Comment: Hello. I tried your suggestion and it sends me this error message "Cannot perform late binding on a NULL reference.' ". Right on this line: "int id = selectedItem.idInscrito;"

Comment: Did you select an item in the `DataGrid` then? Otherwise `GridInscritos.SelectedItem` return `null` just like in the code you posted.